# Macbook Pro late 2016 (Touchbar) / WD elements HDD not in Finder

Tags: finder, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a Macbook Pro late 2016 with Touchbar etc. and a Western Digital Elements external HDD of 1 tb. 
When I plug in my HDD it wont show up in Finder. It takes about ~20 minutes to recognise it, if it recognises it. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not.

When I type the `diskutil list`

I get the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +249.7 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 F81477CF-32B7-44F7-A787-C280104BB711
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data LTKort                  1000.0 GB  disk2s2
```

But it wont show in Finder, So I tried to eject it with: `diskutil eject disk2` but it says: `Volume timed out while waiting to eject`

Why doesn't it show in Finder directly and what can I do about it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268930/macbook-pro-retina-13-inch-early-2015-usb-wd-hdd-passport-not-in-finder

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder preferences and change the check box beside external disks from **-** to checked.